# use removeClass() on selected class

Tags: jquery

I have a DOM element with 2 classes attached.

I wanted to know if I can call the element with one of the classes, and remove the other class attached.

Let's say this is the code:

```
<span class="leave stay"> a </span>
```

and the jQuery is :

```
$('.stay').removeClass('leave');
```

It seems like it is impossible.

Do you have an idea why it ain't working?

Thanks,
robi

Comment: What is your question - what is not working exactly?

Comment: The javascript statement looks good to do what you have stated. It removes the class `leave` from a `element` with class `stay`

Answer (score 3):

What you have works, just make sure it's inside a [`document.ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler (so it runs once the DOM is loaded, and your elements are there to be found), like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('.stay').removeClass('leave');  
});
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/uYhLK/).

Comment: OK I understood the problem, it was a little bit before, I have :   var className = $(this).attr("id");
$(".className").show();                                                I can't do it, because the JS knows className as a string.             Do you have an idea on how to solve it?

Comment: @robi - Just add it in, like this: `$("." + className).show();`